# An analogue of Beurling's theorem on the Heisenberg group.

Tags: harmonic-analysis, heisenberg-group

Let $f\in L^2(\Bbb R^n)$ and $d\geq0$. Then $$\int_{\Bbb R^n}\int_{\Bbb R^n} \frac{|f(x)||\hat f(y)|}{(1+|x|+|y|)^d} e^{|x||y|} dxdy<\infty$$
implies that $f=0$ when $d\leq n$.

The analogue of this theorem in the Heisenberg group $ \Bbb H^n$ for $f\in L^2(\Bbb H^n)$  is as follows
$$\int_{\Bbb H^n}\int_{\Bbb R} \frac{|f(z,t)|\quad||\hat f(\lambda)||_{HS}}{(1+|t|+| \lambda|)^d} e^{|t||\lambda|} d\mu(\lambda)dzdt<\infty$$
implies that $f=0$ when $d\leq n/2+1$.
for more detail we can see this [https://www.researchgate.net/publication/231999338_An_Analogue_of_Beurling's_Theorem_for_the_Heisenberg_Group](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/231999338_An_Analogue_of_Beurling%27s_Theorem_for_the_Heisenberg_Group)

my question why the author doesen't put the following condition
$$\int_{\Bbb H^n}\int_{\Bbb R} \frac{|f(z,t)|\quad||\hat f(\lambda)||_{HS}}{(1+|(z,t)|+| \lambda|)^d} e^{|(z,t)||\lambda|} d\mu(\lambda)dzdt<\infty.$$

Comment: Are all the integrals assumed to be finite?  Your displayed integrals are all missing right-hand sides.

Comment: Yes, all the integrals are finite